# Getting caller name during ajaxSend or ajaxSuccess

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to extend all of my application's ajax calls with some special case handlers and be able to refire the method that started the ajax call if I need to.  The problem I am having is I cannot get the name of the calling function that triggered the ajax call from my anonymous function event handlers, either ajaxSend or ajaxSuccess.  I have tried all of the variations of caller/callee that are commented below plus many others.  Here is some sample code:

```
  var ajaxcaller;
  $(document).ajaxSend(function(event,xhr,settings){
       // Before we fire off our call lets store the caller.
       // ajaxcaller = arguments.callee.caller.name;          
       //alert("get caller:"+arguments.callee.caller.name);
       //alert("get caller:"+caller.name);
       //alert("get caller:"+this.caller.toString());
       //alert("get caller:"+event.caller.toString());
  });
  $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event,xhr,settings){
       var xobj = $.parseJSON(request.responseText);
       if(xobj.ReFire === 1){
           //Successful ajax call but not results we expected, let's refire
           //Fix some params automagically here then
           //SOME CODE HERE THAT Refires my caller
        }
  });
  $(document).ajaxError(function(event,xhr,settings){
       var xobj = $.parseJSON(request.responseText);
       if(xobj.ReFire === 1){
           //Fix some params automagically here then
           //SOME CODE HERE THAT Refires my caller
        }
  });
```

Comment: What do you expect to get back as the caller?

Comment: Say I have this code:

Comment: Say I have this code:  function getRecords(){  $.post(someURL, params, function(results) { //do something with results }, "json");  //do some more stuff here. }  I would want to have my var ajaxCaller to get set to "getRecords".  Now I know that perhaps the source may be another anonymous function (perhaps some click event that was binded) but for the most part if I can get the caller 90% of the time that would still work.  Alternatively, even if I can get the source (toString) then I could eval that which would rerun what I need to rerun.

Comment: @user2242389, Did my solution worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea, however I am not sure how reliable it would be, but you could intercept `jQuery.ajax` calls and append a `caller` property to the `options` that would reference the calling function as well as an `args` property that would reference the arguments that were passed to that function.

I am sure that if you play around with that idea, you will find a solution to your problem. If you don't like the idea of overriding `jQuery.ajax`, you could simply make sure to pass those references as options in all your ajax calls.

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/zVsk2/**

```
jQuery.ajax = (function (fn) {
    return function (options) {
        var caller = arguments.callee.caller;
        options.caller = caller;
        options.args = caller.arguments;
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(jQuery.ajax);

$(document).ajaxSend(function (e, xhr, options) {
    console.log('caller', options.caller);
    console.log('args', options.args);
});

function getRecords(someArgument) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/json/',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            json: JSON.stringify({ test: someArgument})
        }
    });
}

getRecords(1);
getRecords(2);
```